# how to get the current tab url in popover for safari extension

Tags: popover, safari-extension

Hi There best collegue,

Currently im busy with developing a bookmarker extension for safari and running up against a problem. How can i acces the current tab url in the popover?

Tnx in advance:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popover doesn't have access to `safari.application` so can't get the current URL directly, but it can call functions in the global page which can.

In your global page:

```
function currentUrl() {
    return safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url;
}
```

Then in the popover:

```
alert(safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.currentUrl());
```

Ensure that the Access Level is set to 'All' in the Extension builder and secure pages are included otherwise the URL will sometimes be undefined.